# How to load html file in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

My backbone view folder:

```
view.html
tmpl/t01.html
tmpl/t02.html
tmpl/t03.html
```

view.html:

```
...
<div id="tmpl"></id>
```

in view.html, when I click button 01, I would like to display tmpl/t01.html within view.html, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this with an ajax request manually:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'tmpl/t01.html',
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(data){
    var compiledTpl = _.template( data, {} );
    $('#tmpl').html(compiledTpl);
  }
);}
```

Or with [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for require.js

```
require(["text!tmpl/t01.html"],
  function(html) {
    var compiledTpl = _.template( html, {} );
    $('#tmpl').html(compiledTpl);
  }
);
```